# addEventListener() gets called only on the last loop cycle

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, closures, addeventlistener

I've been trying to solve this for hours with no luck.
Looked through all the similar questions asked on stackoverflow but neither of the solutions seems to work for me.

I have an array of videos I'm looping through. I need to plug in each video into the audio element to quickly get its' duration and the exact time it appears in the playlist.

What I had originally is this:

```
// Set time in playlist for each video
for (let index=0; index<this.playlist.length; index++) {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  console.log('INDEX: ' + index);
  self.playlist[index].timeInPlaylist = [];
  self.playlist[index].duration = 0;
  audio.setAttribute('src', self.playlist[index].bucketRef);
  audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
     videoDuration = Math.round(e.currentTarget.duration);
     console.log("Duration of video number " + index + ": " + 
     videoDuration + " seconds");
     self.playlist[index].duration = videoDuration;
     self.playlist[index].timeInPlaylist[0] = playlistLength;
     playlistLength = playlistLength + videoDuration;
     self.playlist[index].timeInPlaylist[1] = playlistLength;
  });
};
```

Running this code was keeping the index the same and the output was the length of the last video in the array logged 3 times. Then after digging through it, I realized I need some type of closure because of adding event listeners inside the loop. So I did a little refactoring and came to this current version:

```
function log(e, index) {
  videoDuration = Math.round(e.currentTarget.duration);
  console.log("Duration of video number " + index + ": " + videoDuration + " seconds");
  self.playlist[index].duration = videoDuration;
  self.playlist[index].timeInPlaylist[0] = playlistLength;
  playlistLength = playlistLength + videoDuration;
  self.playlist[index].timeInPlaylist[1] = playlistLength;
}

// Set time in playlist for each video
for (let index=0; index<this.playlist.length; index++) {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  console.log('INDEX: ' + index);
  self.playlist[index].timeInPlaylist = [];
  self.playlist[index].duration = 0;
  audio.setAttribute('src', self.playlist[index].bucketRef);
  debugger;
  (function() {
      var i = index;
      audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(e) { log(e, i); });
  })();
};
```

This has solved my issue with indexes; however, I'm still only getting the duration of the last video in the array.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3as6.png)

I would really appreciate some feedback. This issue has been killing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the source attribute of the same audio element synchronously in the loop, as well as adding extra event listeners to the one audio element.

After the loop terminates and the audio element loads the audio for the last `src` attribute it was set with, all the event listeners are called with details of the *one-and-the-same* last play list item.

You will need to redesign the code to run asynchronously and load one audio element with different audio sources sequentially, or create a new AUDIO element for each play list item. Alternatively leave the duration blank until the user selects an item to play (just a thought).

Note you should not be needing to create a closure to hold the value of `index` - this is a mistake in debugging: `let` in the for loop declaration of `index` creates a separate lexical reference to the variable for each loop iteration. The value of `index` seen in a function expression within the loop is that of the iteration when the expression was evaluated.

Comment: Thank you! Everything you said makes perfect sense and looking at the code with fresh eyes really helps. I'll probably create a separate audio element instance for each of the array items. Unfortunately, the idea of having a user choose the video doesn't work with the concept of the player I'm building. My app shows the user only a single video crated from the fragments. It seamlessly plays / stitches videos from any given array of videos with one single seek bar; so I need to know the duration of each of the videos right when the component is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a closure but in an incorrect manner.

Replace this part in your code code

`(function() {
      var i = index;
      audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(e) { log(e, i); });
  })();`

with

```
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", (function(audioObj, index) {
    return function(){
      log(audioObj, index); 
    }
  })(this, index)
 );
```

Doing this should give you direct access to the audio object inside **log** function to get its duration rather than relying on the event object.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! However, after plugging in this code and switching e.currentTarget.duration to e.duration, this (NotANumber) is what I get logged in the console "Duration of video number 0: NaN seconds, Duration of video number 1: NaN seconds, Duration of video number 2: NaN seconds"

Comment: Could you please create a JsFiddle of your code so that I can inspect what may be wrong ?